# Set Version number of TFS Build in C# File

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfsbuild

Hy,

is it possible to set the number of the TFS Build in a C# File?

The TFS Build should replace the version number with the current one.

> public const string SERVICE_VERSION = "2.0 Build: 20130518.1";

EDIT:
The const is in a class called SharedMethods:

> ```
> public static class SharedMethods 
> {
>     public const string SERVICE_VERSION = "2.0 Build: 20130518.1";
>     ...
>     ...
> }
> ```

The TFS build should check out the element, update the version, check in the element and continue the normal build process.

Comment: Do you mean from a custom build task, or from code in the assembly being built?

Comment: from a custom build task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this article:
[Create a Custom WF Activity to Sync Version and Build Numbers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2009/11/18/how-to-create-a-custom-workflow-activity-for-tfs-build-2010.aspx)

It describes how to change the version number in the AssemblyInfo.cs file. You could tweak this to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If your file contains only theses lines, perhaps you could do something like that :

```
    <WriteLinesToFile File="$(VersionFilePath)" Lines="public const string SERVICE_VERSION = %22$(Version)%22%3B" Overwrite="true" Encoding="ASCII"/>
```

Note that " should be replaced by %22 and ; by %3B (when you add a ';', a new line char is inserted).

Otherwise, you could write C# code in a msbuild to do what you want. An exemple :

```
<UsingTask TaskName="UpdateApplicationRevision" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
   <ParameterGroup>
        <ProjectFilePath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
        <Task>
          <Reference Include="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.dll" />
          <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
            <![CDATA[
      var project = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(ProjectFilePath);
      var property = project.GetProperty("ApplicationRevision");
      property.UnevaluatedValue = "" + (System.Int32.Parse(property.EvaluatedValue) + 1);
      project.Save();
]]>
        </Code>
    </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

Here, I modify a csproj (xml) file, but feel free to write your own code to read your file and update it...

Comment: Unfortunately, the file does not only contain these lines. The string const is a static class called SharedMethods